# How to modify a script for using it with more files?

Tags: shell-script, bioinformatics

I have this small script named `my_script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

size=$(infoseq -auto -nocolumns -delimiter ',' -only -noheading -length lambda_8.fa)
size=$(( $size - 200 ))
pos=$(($RANDOM % $size))
size2=$(( $pos + 200 ))
extractseq lambda_8.fa -regions $pos-$size2
```

What I want is to be able to use it with different files and saving the output in another file based on the inputfile so I can use it like:

```
bash my_script.sh file.fa
```

and the output could look like `200_pb_file.fa`.

Comment: I don't know what `infoseq` command do but maybe you need replace `lambda_8.fa` in the code with `"$1"`

Comment: @αғsнιη the infoseq command gives the lenght of a sequence.  So if I replace lambda_8.fa with $1 in the script then I define the variable $1? Or what would you recommend? Thanks

Comment: and what output returns the last line? and also `200_pa_` in  `200_pb_file.fa` is a fixed string or that should be a generated string in somewhere in the script?

Comment: #This script extract 200 random characters from a sequence 
#gives the length of the lambda_8.fa file
size=$(infoseq -auto -nocolumns -delimiter ',' -only -noheading -length lambda_8.fa)
#Subsract 200 characters
size=$(( $size - 200 ))
#Establish the start position
pos=$(($RANDOM % $size))
#Establish the end position
size2=$(( $pos + 200 ))
#Extract the 200 characters from lambda_8.fa file
extractseq lambda_8.fa -regions $pos-$size2

Makes sense? :)